# Tweening polygon Kinetic JS

Tags: polygon, kineticjs, tween

Can I change the size of polygon wchich I defined by points?

```
var pierwszy = new Kinetic.Polygon({
points: [0, 0, 150, 0, 80, 150, 0, 150],
fillPatternImage: images.img1,
stroke: 'black',
strokeWidth: 5,
});
```

I have tried to just change points and add to tween atriubutes, but it doesn't work.
scaleX and scaleY work very well, but the background image is bluring.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is useful for you,In my situation is ,I want to change the shape of the polygon with a tween:

```
poly1= new Kinetic.Polygon({
points: [0, 0, 150, 0, 80, 150, 0, 150],
fill: shadowLightColor,
stroke: '#bbbbbb',
strokeWidth: 1
});
layer.add(poly1);
poly1.tween = new Kinetic.Tween({
    node: poly1,
    duration: 1,
    points: [0, 0, 300, 0, 200, 150, 0, 150],
    easing: Kinetic.Easings.StrongEaseInOut
}).play();
```